# Flutter web: how could a child Container widget prevent its parent scrollable widget from scrolling when the mouse pointer is over the child widget?

Tags: flutter, web, widget, scrollview, parent-child

I have a child Container widget in a parent scrollable widget. Is there any way to prevent parent widget from receiving mouse events (scrolling) via trackpad/mouse when the mouse pointer is over the child widget?

I tried to wrap the child Container widget in a GestureDetector but it doesn't work.

====================
Found solution:
Wrap the child widget in a Listener, handle Pointer Signal events and then resolve some Pointer events that I don't want the parent widget to receive. Thank you.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 600.0),
            Listener(
              onPointerSignal: (pointerSignal) {
                debugPrint('onPointerSignal: $pointerSignal');
                if (pointerSignal is PointerScrollEvent) {
                  GestureBinding.instance.pointerSignalResolver
                      .register(pointerSignal, (PointerSignalEvent event) {
                    // handle the event and prevent parent receiving it
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 100.0,
                child: const Text(
                    'Expecting parent widget not receive pointer events when mouse pointer is over me'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(color: Colors.green, height: 600.0),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: try ignorePointer

Comment: Wrap the child in an IgnorePointer causing it could not receive any mouse pointer events while the parent is still scrolling. It is not correct as my expectation. I need the child widget is still receiving mouse pointer events while the parent widget is not.

Comment: I did it.
I wrap the child widget in a Listener, handle Pointer Signal events and then resolve some Pointer events that I don't want the parent widget to receive.